# How do I let the pug engine not to convert some !{} syntax?

Tags: pug

If I want to quote the literal `!{a}` in the code. What should I do?

```
- var a = '5' // I have to use the variable name "a"
script.
  var str = "!{a}"
```

It will converts to:

```
<script>
  var a = "5";  // I want to have the string equals "!{a}", not "5"
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html) to output the string `'!{a}'`:

```
script.
  var str = "#{'!{a}'}"
```

Result:

```html
<script>
  var str = "!{a}"
</script>
```

A bit weird, but works.

---

Another possibility is to store the string `'!{a}'` to a variable and use interpolation to output it:

```
- var foo = '!{a}'
script.
  var str = "#{foo}"
```

Result:

```html
<script>
  var str = "!{a}"
</script>
```

---

Addendum:

I thought that escaping the interpolation with a backslash would work, but it doesn't because the `!` is converted to a `#`:

```
script.
  var str = "\!{a}"
```

Result:

```html
<script>
  var str = "#{a}"
</script>
```

Looks like a bug to me.